# Cocos2dx Windows Phone 8.1: Seperate Characters in RTL Label

Tags: cocos2d, cocos2d-x, windows-phone-8

I use below code to show a text :

`auto label = Label::createWithSystemFont("سلام و خداحافظ", "BTitrBold", 24);`

( RTL text like Persian, Arabic and Hebrew)
This code works fine in both `**Android**` and `**iOS**`. But when I run project on `**WindowsPhone8.1-universal**` device, the label shows the characters not only **separated** but also **LTR** , as below screenshot:

[image: winphone]

I was faced same problem in Android long time ago. But It solved [Link](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/93442/right-to-left-text-direction-in-cocos2dx).

In order to solving problem I compiled [**fribidi**](https://github.com/behdad/fribidi/) library for windowsPhone. this library solve separated character problems (somehow) but still Wrapping is a big problem.

Please solve Right-To-Left problem in WindowPhone8.1. We really miss this platform's store.

PS: cocos2dx 3.10

Comment: Please, check my answer here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/153372/45544